# Install CLT: '919 hours remaining?'

Tags: xcode

Installing CLT (in the course of installing Xcode), the estimated time seems unreasonable - 919 hours, 7 minutes. Has it ever taken that long, and what should I do?

Comment: 38.29 days _does_ seem to be rather excessive, and no install has ever taken that long. I'd use Activity Monitor and/or Terminal to kill the install process, then poke around the logs to see if there are any oddities. You could always restart the Mac and try the install again.

Comment: I had this same issue with the displayed ETA being unreasonably high, but it only took around 10 minutes. Not sure if you'll have the same luck but I'd just leave it for a little bit first